# De-focusing (scattering) ion beam using quadrupole magnets?

Tags: plasma-physics

It is a well known fact that quadrupole magnetic array can effectively focus an ion beam for example in a particle accelerator. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_magnet)
Would it be possible to create a special magnetic arrangement to achive exactly the opposite effect, I mean to de-focus (scatter) the ion beam? If yes, what kind of magnet assembly could do that?

Comment: Actually the quadrupole arrangement you refer to focuses in one direction but de-focuses in the other but you’d have to specify what you want in ordre to work out a configuration.  Are you looking for the analogue of a beam expander?

Comment: Yes, the "beam expander" is a very good analogue to what I really want: expand a highly focused ion beam (plasma beam) into a much larger area beam.

Comment: I know, the classic quadrupole can focus in one direction and de-focus in the other, si my idea was to make a quadrupole magnet array, but all magnets in the same direction. (for example all magnets North pole looking inward in the quadrupole). What would be the effect of such an array to a plasma beam?